# Extremely slow "row_number() over order" query

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, window-functions

I have a users table with columns (id, xp, ...) and around 1.5 million rows.

I am getting someone's position in the XP leaderboard with the following query (which took 33 seconds to execute):

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE WITH counts AS (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                                id,
                                ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY xp DESC)
                FROM
                    users
            ) SELECT
                *
            FROM
                counts
            WHERE
                id=1;
```

```sql
Subquery Scan on counts  (cost=344492.80..395160.57 rows=7404 width=16) (actual time=30683.244..32174.117 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: (counts.id = '1'::bigint)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 1481060
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=344492.80..376651.79 rows=1480702 width=24) (actual time=30679.440..32034.921 rows=1481061 loops=1)
        Group Key: users.id, row_number() OVER (?)"
        Planned Partitions: 64  Batches: 65  Memory Usage: 4369kB  Disk Usage: 125960kB
        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=212155.06..238067.34 rows=1480702 width=24) (actual time=2983.137..20302.548 rows=1481061 loops=1)
              ->  Sort  (cost=212155.06..215856.81 rows=1480702 width=16) (actual time=2983.082..5040.782 rows=1481061 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: users.xp DESC
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 37760kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..35094.02 rows=1480702 width=16) (actual time=25.467..880.626 rows=1481061 loops=1)
Planning Time: 2.593 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 14
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true"
  Timing: Generation 12.061 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 1.503 ms, Emission 26.086 ms, Total 39.650 ms"
Execution Time: 32325.206 ms
```

My table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id                    bigint                                        NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT users_pkey
            PRIMARY KEY,
    xp                    bigint               DEFAULT 0                NOT NULL,
    ...
);
CREATE INDEX user_xp_leaderboard_index
    ON users (xp DESC, id ASC);
```

But it is extremely slow. Although it is not surprising considering it sorts the whole table and filter it, I don't know how I could improve/optimize this query.

I did `SET work_mem TO '1 GB';`. It helped a bit but not much.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: An index on `xp`?

Comment: `Filter: (counts.id = '90076279646212096'::bigint)` <<-- where does this stem from?

Comment: I am new to indexes. Could you explain how I should create the index and change my query according to that? @Amadan

Comment: `90076279646212096` was the ID I used instead of `1` in the sample query. I will fix that. Sorry. @wildplasser

Comment: You could start by making `id` a primary key, if it **is** a PK. (otherwise you should not name it `id`)

Comment: `id` is the primary key. How should I name it? @wildplasser

Comment: DISTINCT is useless in this query. Remove it.

Comment: Added table definition @wildplasser

Comment: I don't want the query to ignore people with the same XP value. I want the true row number @forpas

Comment: @Midorina since id is the primary key of the table then all rows are distinct. Adding DISTINCT slows down th equery.

Comment: Thank you. Removed the distinct keyword. It helped a bit.

Comment: Creating an index with `xp` as the first column could help.

Comment: I created an index with this query `CREATE INDEX xp_leaderboard_index ON users (id, xp DESC);`
Should I delete this index and put the XP as the first column? @wildplasser

Comment: Yes, I would propose that. (having `id` as its first column is (more or less) useless, since that is already covered by the PK/Unique

Comment: That actually helped a bit further. Thank you. @wildplasser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the query like this:

```
select count(*)
from users u 
where u.xp >= (select u2.xp from users u2 where u2.id = 1);
```

This can take advantage of an index on `users(id, xp)`.  This should totally eliminate any sorting.  An index on `users(xp)` could also be helpful if the rows are quite wide and Postgres can use an index-only scan.

Comment: Thank you. You're a legend. The queries take around 100 ms with this. But, I have a few questions. I have this index: `CREATE INDEX user_xp_leaderboard_index ON users (xp DESC, id);`
1) Should id be there or not?
2) If yes, which one should I input first? `xp DESC` or `id`?

Comment: I asked this because in the analyze section, it says "partial aggregate" when using the index I have created

Comment: @Midorina . . . The answer suggests which indexes are helpful.  `(xp, id)` does not have the keys in the right order.

Comment: in my post's comments, @wildplasser suggested otherwise. that's why I asked.

Comment: @Midorina . . . That is for the query in your question.  And an index on `xp` could help this query, under some circumstances, but the effect might not be very large.